# Probability of median of 3 values drawn from $U(0, 1)$ being less than $c$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Draw $x_1, x_2, x_3$ from $U(0, 1)$ what is the probability that the median of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is $< c$?

The approach that I had in mind is to find the CDF of the second order statistic (the median in this case), differentiate it to get the PDF, and then integrate from 0 to $c$ to get the probability. But is  there a more clever approach given that there are only 3 values here?

One approach that I just thought of is to consider the complement, the probability that the median is greater than $c$. This means exactly 2 of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are $\geq c$ or all 3 are greater than $c$.

The latter occurs with probability $\left(1 - c \right)^3$. The former occurs with probability $\binom{3}{2} \left(1 - c \right)^2 c$.

So the probability that median is less than $c$ should be
$$
1 - \left(1 - c\right)^3 - \binom{3}{2} \left(1 - c\right)^2 c
$$
?

Answer (score 1):

Let the median of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be denoted $M$.  Then $\Pr[M \le c]$ is equivalent to saying that at most one of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is greater than $c$.  This is a binomial probability where the probability that any given $x_i$ is less than or equal to $c$ is equal to $c$; i.e., let $Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(c)$ count the number of $x_i$ that are less than or equal to $c$.  Then $$\Pr[M \le c] = \Pr[Y \ge 2] = \binom{3}{3} c^3 (1-c)^{3-3} + \binom{3}{2} c^2 (1-c)^{3-2} = c^3 + 3 c^2 (1-c) = c^2(3-2c).$$  This of course is equivalent to your answer.

Comment: Also: ${\mathsf P(X_{(2)}\leqslant c) \\= 3!\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant c\lt 1}\int_0^c F_{X}(x)f_{X}(x)(1-F_X(x))~\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant c}\\=6\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant c\lt 1}\int_0^c x-x^2\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant c}\\= (3c^2-2c^3)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant c\lt 1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant c}}$  So all approaches yield the same result.